# How should I compare two methods for obtaining the frequency of several events?

Tags: regression, correlation, bland-altman-plot

I am using two different methods to obtain the frequency of several events.  Can I use a scatter plot to graph the frequency of an event obtained by Method A against the one obtained by Method B?  And afterwards, report the correlation coefficient to state that, since they strongly correlate, they can be used interchangeably depending on the resources available?

Or should I use a Bland-Altman plot or a least products regression analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Using the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, compare the two empirical distributions. If you reject the null hypothesis, you cannot use them interchangeably. If you fail to reject, perhaps you pursue something along the lines you mentioned.